# Spring boot application fails to start on jboss eap 6.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jboss

I have updated my project gradle dependency to spring boot 1.5.9 version.
After creating war application fails to start.

1. In startup I can see it is trying to start with spring boot 2.1 autoconfigurer.
2. There are many errors starts with  Could not index class.
3. Also I have included hibernate 4.3 jar in gradle dependency but its importing hibernate core entity manager & validator 5.X jar in packaged war.

Any pointers on below issue would be of great help.

Final error is as highlighted below not sure what is the use of this jar.

JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar

```
17:34:47,921 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015852: Could not index class org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/artemis/ArtemisEmbeddedServerConfiguration.class at xxx/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unknown tag! pos=20 poolCount = 270
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.processConstantPool(Indexer.java:606) [jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.jandex.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:640) [jandex-1.0.3.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.3.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.ResourceRootIndexer.indexResourceRoot(ResourceRootIndexer.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.annotation.AnnotationIndexProcessor.deploy(AnnotationIndexProcessor.java:51) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]


18:26:08,119 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Test-1.0.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Test-1.0.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "Test-1.0.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:210)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.deploy(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ... 5 more
**Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018104: Deployment error processing SCI for jar: tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar**
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:202)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: Can you please post your grade build file with all dependencies?

Comment: configurations {

    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile.exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat' }  After adding this dependency able to start war loading but now getting eror or logback dependency Deployment error processing SCI for jar: logback-classic-1.1.11.jar

Comment: please update your question with a proper formatting of the grade build file